# Finding where an old NHibernate DLL is referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dll

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC C# project and I'm getting the following error when launching the web app:

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Based on the error and some googling it seems clear that there is something referencing a NHibernate dll version 2.1.0.1001.  However, our project is using NHibernate version 2.1.2.4000 (old, I know).  I've searched the entire solution for any references to that version of NHibernate and cannot find one.  I'm assuming that another DLL that we're using is referencing it, but I don't know the best place to start to figure out which.

Am I on target with what the issue likely is?  Any (hopefully free) dependency tools that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on-target with the basic issue.  Consider a stale output file from your solution too.  A rebuild (i.e. clean and build) should cover that possibility.

A good free tool for checking references in assemblies you reference is Telerik [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

Also, [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may shed some light on the load error.

Comment: Thanks!  I used JustDecompile to figure it out.  In case anyone is interested it ended up being an old version of the Nhibernate lambda extensions.